# How to prevent Vite CSS Splitting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, vite

I'm trying to build a Vue Plugin which contains several UI components (pretty much like Bootstrap). I'm trying to set `build.cssCodeSplit: false` so that the plugin can be installed like `import Ecosphere from 'vue-ecosphere' and used globally, however when I build the plugin, the CSS is being split despite setting the property to` false`.

Here's the repository: https://github.com/bacon-delight/vue-ecosphere
To reproduce,

- Clone the repo
- Create a `.env` with `VITE_PACKAGE_MODE=true`
- Run `npm run build` (Generates `style.css` in the `/dist` directory)

My `vite.config.ts` looks like this:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "node:path";

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };

    return {
        plugins: [
            vue({
                template: {
                    transformAssetUrls: {
                        includeAbsolute: false,
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
            },
        },
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                scss: {
                    additionalData: `@import "@/assets/framework.scss";`,
                },
            },
        },
        build:
            process.env.VITE_PACKAGE_MODE === "true"
                ? {
                        cssCodeSplit: false,
                        lib: {
                            name: "vue-ecosphere",
                            entry: path.resolve(
                                __dirname,
                                "./src/plugin/plugin.ts"
                            ),
                            fileName(format) {
                                return `vue-ecosphere.${format}.js`;
                            },
                        },
                        rollupOptions: {
                            external: ["vue"],
                            output: {
                                globals: {
                                    vue: "Vue",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                  }
                : {},
    };
});
```

Dist gets generated with these files:

```
favicon.ico             logo.png                style.css               vue-ecosphere.es.js     vue-ecosphere.umd.js
```

Can someone please help? I do not know how to prevent the CSS from being separated.